# Expected value of I(X-Y)_(0,+inf) given their respective distributions

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Hello guys I have the following problem and cannot figure out the computation of $\mathbb E(I(X-Y)_{(0, +inf)} )$

Given $X∼Exp(λ)$ and $ Y∼Exp(θ)$.

Let $X$ represent the length of the red petals.

Let $Y$ represent the length of the yellow petals.

Finally let $p=Pr(Y>X)$ be the probability that on average the yellow petals are greater in length than red petals.

**The task is to show that $p$ can obtained in function of  $λ$ and  $θ$.**

I'm stuck here:

$\mathbb E(I(X-Y)_{(0, +inf)} )$

I know the indicator function is distributed as a Bernoulli distribution, but I cant figure out how to get to the expression of p in function of lambda and theta.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is $Esp(\lambda)$?

Comment: Exponentialy distributed

Comment: Its expression is lambda exp(-lambda y) and theta exp(-theta x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent the value  is $P(X>Y)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx \theta e^{-\theta y} dy=\frac {\theta} {\lambda+\theta}$.

I have used the fact that $EI_A=P(A)$ where $A=(X-Y \in (0,\infty)$. Note that $A$ is same as the event $(X>Y)$

Comment: Okay but I want to understand why it is so, I wanted to figure out on how to get to that expression by using the expected value..

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: $EI_A=P(A)$ Take $A=(X-Y \in (0,\infty))$ which means $(X>Y)$

Comment: Would you add it in the answer?

Comment: @Cristian I have done that.